# Is it possible to run two services on the same ports with different IP but on the same machine?

Tags: linux, networking, interface

My question is simple.

Is it possible to run TWO different game servers using exact same port but on different IP's using same network interface on the same server ?

Does each IP adress have it's own port pool or is it limited to machine's network interface ?

Comment: Irrelated, but blocking your site completely to IE users is not particularly fair. If someone want to quickly view the files they shoudln't be *forced* to download another browser or do some trickery.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is possible. You just have to bind on the right IP address/interface each service using the same port.

Ports (be them UDP or TCP) have their own pool per IP address.

You can listen on the same port if you change: IP address or protocol (UDP or TCP).

See: http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/tcp-and-udp-ports-explained/

Answer (score 6):

Yes.
Sockets (IP:Port) come in pairs and have to be unique.
You can also bind multiple IPs to a single NIC.

Answer (score 3):

This is easy only if the application supports binding limitations. If it does not then you can put the app into an LXC container if we are talking about Linux or Java (or something running well under WINE). If Windows does not offer something similar then you can use VMs.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's an entirely valid way to do it. The IP:port combo has to be unique, but you can certainly have port 80 on 1.2.3.4 and on 1.2.3.5.

Answer (score -2):

Via HAproxy you can do it:

https://www.linuxbabe.com/linux-server/ocserv-vpn-server-apache-nginx-haproxy

Best wishes for You,
Kamran

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/536260)